# Linked Lists: How to remove odd numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, linked-list

I am currently taking an online computer science introductory course and have just learned the concept of a linked list. Though I understand the concept of linked lists, I still am unsure as how to deal with linked lists.

As such, I seek out help in solving the following problem, which will be of significant help for my understanding of linked lists:

Write a function (not in LinkedList class definition) that given a linked list, will change that linked list to filter out odd numbers. Immediately after the function returns, the linked list will only have even numbers.

I am unsure as to how to access the nodes in the list and check whether they are odd or even and remove or keep them accordingly.

I apologize if this seems like a trivial question, but I would appreciate any help that might help me learn.

The code for the linked list and node classes (as provided by the online course):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node, end=' ')
            node = node.next
        print('')

    def add_at_head(self, node):
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.length += 1

    def remove_node_after(self, node):
        if node.next is not None:
            temp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            temp.next = None
            self.length -= 1

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        temp.next = None
        self.length -= 1

    def print_backward(self):
        def print_nodes_backward(node):
            if node.next is not None:
                print_nodes_backward(node.next)
            if node is not None:
                print(node, end=' ')

        if self.head is not None:
            print_nodes_backward(self.head)

        print('')
```

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this without knowing how you are representing your linked lists. You should post some of your code showing where you are having trouble.

Comment: @MarkMeyer The thing is I am unsure how to proceed with making the required function. I know I need to check if the elements are odd or even and remove the odds. I know how to do this with lists, but not linked lists.

Comment: The idea is to iterate through the list head-to-tail _while remembering the previous node_; when you find a garbage node, apply `remove_node_after` to the remembered node, or move the head to the current node if we haven't had time to remember anything yet.

Comment: @Amadan that is exactly what I am trying to do, my problem is I am unsure how to iterate through the linked list. Typically for lists/arrays I use while/for loops, but this doesn't work for linked lists. If I can only figure out how to do that, I am sure I can solve it.

Comment: I wish `online course`s would not suggest it was OK to not properly document your code, supplying [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) at the very least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a bare-bones simple linked list that looks like this:

```
class LinkedList:
    class ListNode:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.next = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def add(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = LinkedList.ListNode(data)
        else:
            current_node = self.head
            while current_node.next is not None:
                current_node = current_node.next
            current_node.next = LinkedList.ListNode(data)
    def __str__(self):
        ret = "["
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node is not None:
            ret = ret + str(current_node.data)
            if current_node.next is not None:
                ret = ret + ", "
            current_node = current_node.next
        ret = ret + "]"
        return ret
```

In other words, the `LinkedList` contains a single `head`, which is a `ListNode`. Every element in the Linked List is contained in a `ListNode`, and each `ListNode` points towards the next element in the list.

As you can see, for adding an element to the list, we either create a node at the head if the list is empty (i.e. `self.head is None`), or we traverse to the end of the list by continuously jumping to the `.next` element for each `ListNode`, starting from the `head`. We also use this paradigm for printing a string representation of our list.

So, to remove any node from the linked list, we can simply change the node that references it, so that the node we want to remove gets skipped. At which point it will disappear.

To remove all list nodes containing odd-numbered data, we might do something like this:

```
    def remove_odds(self):
        # special case: head node
        # remove odd head elements by simply setting head to the next element after
        while (self.head is not None) and (self.head.data % 2 == 1):
            self.head = self.head.next
        # regular case: the rest of the nodes
        current_node = self.head
        while (current_node is not None) and (current_node.next is not None):
            # if the next node's data is odd, then
            if current_node.next.data % 2 == 1:
                # skip that node by pointing this node's .next to the next node's .next
                current_node.next = current_node.next.next
            # otherwise, move forwards in the list
            else:
                current_node = current_node.next
```

Proof of concept:

```
>>> lst = LinkedList()
>>> lst.add(2)
>>> lst.add(5)
>>> lst.add(6)
>>> lst.add(3)
>>> lst.add(7)
>>> lst.add(8)
>>> lst.add(10)
>>> lst.add(1)
>>> lst.add(4)
>>> print(lst)
[2, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8, 10, 1, 4]
>>> lst.remove_odds()
>>> print(lst)
[2, 6, 8, 10, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, that is what I did first, but what the online course exercise is looking for a function that is not in the LinkedList class (I am unsure if this is the correct expression).

Comment: I'll leave the information about how to adapt this information as an exercise for you. The algorithm is what's important - what's for certain is that the linked list structure you're trying to interact with should have defined nodes with a `.data` and `.next` field. Look at the documentation and project description you've been given and try to figure out what those are, and then adapt this solution in order to use that.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I have figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Copied from comment: The idea is to iterate through the list head-to-tail *while remembering the previous node*; when you find a garbage node, apply `remove_node_after` to the remembered node, or move the head to the current node if we haven't had time to remember anything yet.

The code would be something like this (untested):

```
class LinkedList:
    # ...
    def delete_if(self, pred):
        prev = None
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            if pred(curr.data):
                if prev:
                    self.remove_node_after(prev)
                else:
                    self.head = curr
            prev = curr
            curr = curr.next

llist.delete_if(lambda x: x % 2 == 1) # delete if odd
```

Comment: Thank you for this, that is what I did first, but what the online course exercise is looking for a function that is not in the LinkedList class (I am unsure if this is the correct expression).

Comment: It does not have to be a method (a function inside a class). The same function works even if not placed inside a class, called as `delete_if(llist, lambda x: x % 2 == 1)` (though you might want to rename `self` to something else, like `llist`, so it's not confusing to humans).

Comment: I believe I have figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Mahmoud AL-Mokdad
# this course on Udemy By SEfactoru right
# use my code 
def filter_even(ll):
    first_node = ll.head
    while (first_node is not None) and (first_node.data % 2 != 0):
        ll.remove_first_node()
        first_node = ll.head
    node = first_node
    while node is not None and node.next is not None:
        if node.next.data % 2 != 0:
            ll.remove_node_after(node)
        else:
            node = node.next
```